# How to share a folder with other user accounts?

Tags: windows-10, file-permissions

There are two user accounts in my pc: one is the administrator account and the other one is a local account. There is a folder which can only be accessed through my (administrator) account but I want that specific folder to also be accessible by the local account so that the local user can see those files (videos and other media files) but cannot delete or modify them.

I am using windows 10, is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Using the administrator account / while logged onto the administrator account / From the administrator account - Right click - "that specific folder" - Properties - 1. Security - 2. Edit - 3. Add - "the local account name" - OK - 4. Highlight "the local account name" - 5. Give it what permissions you want - 6 and 7. OK twice.

[image: Add user and modify permissions on folder]